# Postgres: COPY TO error

Tags: sql, postgresql, error-handling, database-permissions

I need help turning my Postgres table into a CSV file. First, I type

```
sudo su postgres (then I enter my password)
psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

The terminal looks like:

```
postgres=#
```

I typed in the COPY TO command to try to create a .csv file with all the information in my table, but I get an error:

```
postgres=# COPY venues TO '/usr/file.csv';
ERROR:  could not open file "/usr/file.csv" for writing: Permission denied
```

I also tried using the \copy command, but I get:

```
postgres=# \COPY venues TO '/usr/file.csv';
/usr/file.csv: Permission denied
```

I read a couple answers that said that I might not have permission to write in a certain directory. Is this true?

Also, in postgres, the schema lists my_name as the owner of the table I am trying to export information from (venues). However, this is when I am logged in as a postgres user, and I am only able to access the table when I am a logged is as a postgres user.

When I log into postgres by simply typing "psql," I get:

```
my_name=>
```

and when I type the command "\d" to see the tables under this user, I do not see the venues table listed.
Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I might not have permission to write in a certain directory. Is this true?" Your error messages says "Permission denied", what do you think?

Comment: When typying `psql` without arguments you're logging into a different database than `psql -d postgres -U postgres`, which is why it doesn't have the same tables.

Comment: @Mat I wasn't sure what that "Permission denied" was specifically for. That is why I asked

Comment: @hsivru: instead of asking, why didn't you go and check directly? Much faster than typing that whole question here.

Comment: I guess @hsivru meant he was not sure if he has no permission to write to file or to read a table or to run a command... Well it was a file for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
postgres=# COPY venues TO '/tmp/file.csv';
```

should work for u

Comment: thanks! this worked. how come I was able to transfer and create a file in the tmp folder and not in the usr folder? I did change the permissions of the file in the usr folder, but I got the same error as the one is wrote above.

Comment: `/usr` is not writeable by users by default. It's for application and system files. Why would you try to write to `/usr`? Surely you'd use `\copy` and `/home/myusername`...? If you don't specify an absolute path that's what'll happen, e.g. `\copy venues TO 'file.csv'` will store `file.csv` in `$HOME/file.csv`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I did try writing to a file in my /home/myusername/ file, but I was still getting the "Permission denied" message. I was only adding to /usr to check if I am able to create a file from the postgres command line--I wasn't aware that I couldn't add to this file.

Comment: /home/myusername/ not necessarily is writable for user that runs posmaster daemon... this way \copy will work, cos \copy is psql (clientside) command and COPY won't (serverside)